# The expression "commute to something"

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

I'm in a quantum mechanics class, where people started using expressions such as: "operators $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ commute to $i\hbar$", to mean "$\hat{x}\hat{p}-\hat{p}\hat{x}\equiv[\hat{x},\hat{p}]=i\hbar$". I always thought that "commuting" referred to a property of binary operations (not their operands), and that either the binary operation commutes, or it doesn't, but it never "commutes to something" (else than 0).

I can understand how the word "commute" is used in physics very well, but I was wondering if the same would be acceptable in maths, or if it would be flagged as an abuse of language?

Also, if "commuting" refers to a binary operation, is there in maths a distinction between elements that "commute or "don't commute" for the same operation? For example, if the binary operation is matrix multiplication over the set of square matrices of size 2, some elements "commute" (diagonal matrices), while in general 2 matrices will not "commute".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying that an operation $\star$ on a set $S$ is commutative amounts to sayig $a \star b = b\star a$ for all $a, b \in S$. This is typically phrased as saying that all *elements* in $S$ *commute*. If we didn't have to worry about commutativity on the level of individual elements, it would be silly to even describe an operation as *commutative*!

So yes, in math (particularly algebra) it's quite common to talk of individual elements *commuting* with one another (or mentioning that they don't).

I will say that the phrase *commute to* $X$ is new to me, but I don't find it terribly surprising, or offensive to my math sensibilities in the slightest.

To answer your second question: Given a group $G$ and an element $g \in G$, there are several important definitions involving elements commuting.

At the group level, we have the *centralizer* of $G$, defined as $Z(G) = \{x \in G: xy = yx \text{ for all }y \in G\}$; these are the things in $G$ that commute with everything. If it happens that $Z(G) = G$, we say that $G$ is commutative (since groups are assumed to only have a single binary operation we don't mention the operation), or more often, that it's abelian.

On the level of elements, we can define the centralizer of a specific element; $C(g) = \{x \in G: gx = xg\}$. These are all group elements that commute with a fixed group element.

Comment: I agree, it's quite OK, but when you come out of algebra 101, you are more used to "commute" and "don't commute" without expressions such as "commute to something". That's all.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum on centralizers - I'll add that to my repertory of things to describe groups and their elements :-)

Comment: @Frank Yes, it's quite understandable! Like I said, *commute to* is certainly not very common in group theory, although it may be with ring theory, or specific parts of ring theory (although it may be peculiar to physicists, or certain kinds of physicists). You are quite welcome, and you've now got a view of a bigger picture: We speak of (and care about) commutativity on the element-level very much, and have a few fancy terms to describe things!

Answer (score 4):

The reason here is because the operation $[a,b]=ab-ba$ is called the **commutator**, so saying that $a$ and $b$ *commute* to $c$ is saying that their *commutator* is equal to $c$.

This is in much the same was as you might say "$a$ and $b$ multiply to $c$" or "$a$ and $b$ add to $c$".

The reason that this operation is called the commutator is that $[a,b]=0$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ commute with one-another.  So in a sense, the commutator measures how badly commutativity of two elements fails.

Comment: Again, my question is not about what the usage in physics means, or why it comes from "commutator", but rather if the same usage is acceptable in maths, or frowned upon.

Comment: I meant to draw a connection with addition and multiplication, to show that at the very least, there is no hard rule against it.  *Personally*, I wouldn't say it, but as above, I think it is alright.  Heck, saying a diagram commutes doesn't really involve commutativity in the way we usually mean it.

Comment: Ah - I got it! The binary operation here is the commutator itself, not the composition of operators. Very nice!